# Dimension of invariant subspace proof check

Tags: proof-verification, vector-spaces

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ (where $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) and let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$ with minimal polynomial $m$. Prove that $T$ has a 1 or 2 dimensional  subspace $S$ such that $T(S)\subseteq S$.

My attempt: Suppose $p$ is a prime factor of $m$ (so if $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$, $p$ is linear or an irreducible quadratic). Then $m=pq$ for some polynomial $q$, and so $\exists \ v\in V$ s.t. $w:=q(T)v\not=0$, but $p(T)w=0$. Now let $S_T(w;\{0\}):=\{f\in\mathbb{F}[x]: f(T)w=0\}$, and let $g$ denote monic generator of this polynomial ideal. Since $p(T)w=0$, $p\in S_T(w;\{0\})$, and so $g|p$. But since $p$ is prime and $g\not=1$ (because otherwise, $S_T(w;\{0\})=\mathbb{F}[x]$. So $w=Iw=0$, giving a contradiction), we have $g=p$. But since $\text{deg}(g)=\text{dim}S_T(w,\{0\})$, we have that $T$ has either a 1 dimensional cyclic subspace (i.e. has an eigenvalue) or $T$ has a 2 dimensional cyclic subspace. Since cyclic subspaces are $T$-invariant, we are done.

Does this argument look correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need something more in terms of the minimal polynomial to assert that $V$ has any non-trivial $T$ invariant sub spaces at all.